# Angular: *ngFor loop giving me error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, loops, angular-material

**Problem Statement**

When I am using `*ngFor` in the HTML, it throws me the error: `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`, even though I am using an array in the `*ngFor` loop.

---

**Code**

**HTML** I am using Angular Material's `mat-chips` and inside the mat chip I am using the `*ngFor` and that's where the error is.

```
<mat-form-field class="techSkillsContain" appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Type in a technical skill</mat-label>
                    <input matInput placeholder="i.e Java" type="text" maxlength="40" [matChipInputFor]="techSkills"
                        (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addTechSkill($event)">
                    <mat-hint>Press enter after you type</mat-hint>
                </mat-form-field>

                <br><br>

                <mat-chip-list #techSkills>
                    <mat-chip [removable]="true" *ngFor="let techSkill of techSkills" // <== Error HERE
                        (removed)="removeSkill(techSkill)">
                        {{techSkill}}
                        <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
                    </mat-chip>
                </mat-chip-list>
```

**TypeScript**

This is my component where the techSkills array is. The error is saying that it is not an array even though it is.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatChipInputEvent } from '@angular/material/chips';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account-sign-up',
  templateUrl: './account-sign-up.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account-sign-up.component.scss']
})

export class AccountSignUpComponent implements OnInit {

  private techSkills: String[] = []; // <== The console says this is not an array, even though it is...
  private softSkills: String[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  removeSkill(skill: String): void {
    // If the skill is a tech skill, then it will remove it from the tech skill array
    if (this.techSkills.indexOf(skill) === this.techSkills.indexOf(skill)) {
      const index = this.techSkills.indexOf(skill);

      if (index >= 0) {
        this.techSkills.splice(index, 1);
      }
      // If the skill is a soft skill, then it will remove it from the soft skill array
    } else {
      const index = this.softSkills.indexOf(skill);

      if (index >= 0) {
        this.softSkills.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  addTechSkill(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    // Add our skill to the tech skills
    if ((value || '').trim()) {
      this.techSkills.push(value.trim());
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }

  }

  addSoftSkill(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    // Add our skill to the tech skills
    if ((value || '').trim()) {
      this.softSkills.push(value.trim());
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }
  }
}
```

What is going on here exactly? I must be overlooking something small or something. Am I losing my mind because I see an array but the console says it's not an array? Help me out, please.

---

**Expected Results**

The `*ngFor` loop should iterate through the elements with no problem and without error. Recognizing that it is iterating through an array.

---

**Actual Results**

The `*ngFor` loop is not recognizing the techSkills array as far as I can tell and therefore not able to iterate through it.

Comment: Make sure `techSkills` is an array.

Comment: @Caramiriel Ah-ha. Could be, let me try fixing that...

Comment: @Caramiriel you fixed it! Thank you! Please post your answer so I can give you the rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On its own, the following code is perfectly valid:

```
<mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let techSkill of techSkills">
        content
    </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

The difference is making the chiplist available as a reference `#techSkills`:

```
<mat-chip-list #techSkills> <!-- here -->
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let techSkill of techSkills">
        content
    </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Within that scope, `techSkills` is now an object pointing to the chiplist and not the array that you're expecting. The array still exists, but it is shadowed by the `#techSkills`.